# Re-Format data with multiple headers to long format with one header row becoming data in a new column

Tags: r

I regularly receive data that is formatted with multiple headers and merged cells (yes..excel). Typically these data come in the form of 2+ merged cells representing sample sites, over the top of a number of observations in columns representing parameters of interest for that site. I am using the "openxlsx" package to read in the data with the read.xlsx function shown below (won't run just for reference):

```
read.xlsx('Mussels.xlsx',
              detectDates = T,
              sheet = 2,
              fillMergedCells = T, 
              startRow = 2)
```

**An example:** I am currently working with invasive mussel survey data where I have 25 lengths for two species for each of 14 sites, which I've abbreviated for ease here for ease:

```
lendat <- data.frame(site.a = c("species.1",1,1,1,1),
                     site.a = c("species.2",2,2,2,2), 
                     site.b = c("species.1",3,3,3,3),
                     site.b = c("species.2",4,4,4,4),
                     check.names = F)
```

I would like to be able to write some code that will re-format these data into long form where the column names become values under a new column named "site", and the first row of data becomes the other column names representing the lengths for each species like this:

```
data_form <- data.frame(site = c(rep("site.a", 4), rep("site.b",4)),
                        species.1 = c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3),
                        species.2 = c(2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4))
```

**Update based on @Ronak Shah answer**

Using code from the accepted answer below with the actual data results in a tibble with no data. I discovered that the issue arises with the filter step when decimal values are introduced in the data (actual data contains decimal values). I thought this was a data format issue (example data are all factors) but even when this is true the decimal data are changed into NA's. See example:

```
lendat <- data.frame(site.a = c("species.1", 1.1,2.2,3,4),
                     site.a = c("species.2",5,6,7,8), 
                     site.b = c("species.1", 9,10,11,12),
                     site.b = c("species.2",13,14,15,16),
                     check.names = F)
str(lendat)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ site.a: Factor w/ 5 levels "1.1","2.2","3",..: 5 1 2 3 4
 $ site.a: Factor w/ 5 levels "5","6","7","8",..: 5 1 2 3 4
 $ site.b: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","11","12",..: 5 4 1 2 3
 $ site.b: Factor w/ 5 levels "13","14","15",..: 5 1 2 3 4
```

I split the piped code out to go line by line

```
#Get data in long format
pivot_longer(junk, cols = everything(), names_to = 'site') %>%
  #Create a new column with column names
  mutate(col = paste0('species', .copy)) %>%
  #Remove the values from the first row
  filter(!grepl('\\D', value)) %>%
  #Remove .copy column which was created
  select(-.copy) %>%
  #Group by the new column
  group_by(col) %>%
  #Add a row index
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  #Get data in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
  #Remove row index
  select(-row) %>%
  #Arrange data according to site information
  arrange(site)

x <- pivot_longer(junk, cols = everything(), names_to = 'site')
x
x <- mutate(x, col = paste0('species', .copy))
x
x <- filter(x, !grepl('\\D', value))
x
x <- select(.data = x, -.copy)
x
x <- group_by(x, col)
x
x <- mutate(x, row = row_number())
x
x <- pivot_wider(x, names_from = col, values_from = value)
x
x <- select(x, -row)
x
x <- arrange(x, site)
x
```

The code executes but leaves NA's in the final tibble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Get data in long format
pivot_longer(lendat, cols = everything(), names_to = 'site') %>%
    #Create a new column with column names
    mutate(col = paste0('species', .copy)) %>%
    #Remove the values from the first row
    filter(!grepl('[A-Za-z]', value)) %>%
    #Remove .copy column which was created
    select(-.copy) %>%
    #Group by the new column
    group_by(col) %>%
    #Add a row index
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    #Get data in wide format
    pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
    #Remove row index
    select(-row) %>%
    #Arrange data according to site information
    arrange(site)


#   site   species1 species2
#  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   
#1 site.a 1.1      5       
#2 site.a 2.2      6       
#3 site.a 3        7       
#4 site.a 4        8       
#5 site.b 9        13      
#6 site.b 10       14      
#7 site.b 11       15      
#8 site.b 12       16
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with the example. Expanding to my larger dataset is proving tricky. Can you tell me what the "\\D" pattern represents? I found that it is for digits in the help documentation?

Comment: `\\D` is to detect non-digits. So using `filter(!grepl('\\D', value))` we remove all the rows which has no digits in it. So it removes like `"species.1"`, `"species.2"` etc.

Comment: That makes sense. It appears the issue has something to do with the fact that my actual data has decimal values. These are turned into NA's during the filter step. I edited the question above to reflect this issue. Any idea here?

Comment: So it's detecting the decimal point during the filter step and removing all my data i think?

Comment: See updated answer. I use `filter(!grepl('[A-Za-z]', value))` instead.